# onDestroy mediaplayer release

Tags: android, media-player, ondestroy

I want when I click on back button on the phone to close current activity and get back to menu and stop Media Player
But I get error: `Unfortunately Weapons has stopped! upon clicking on back button`
So how to fix that?

```
public class pushke extends Activity {

    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.guns);
        initControls();

        final MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uzi);
        ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.pause();
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }
                else{
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                { }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                { }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

**Logcat:**

[image]

Comment: In your LOG.. showing NullpointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)  I want when I click on back button on the phone to close current
>   activity and get back to menu and stop Media Player

1) What do you mean by menu? I mean application menu or device menu or notification bar etc.

> 2) But I get error: Unfortunately Weapons has stopped! upon clicking on
>   back button So how to fix that?

2)

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mp!=null){
             mp.stop();
             mp.release();
             mp = null;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    setContentView(R.layout.guns);
    initControls();

    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uzi);
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For example: I have 2 activities, Menu and Guns. I am using Activity Guns and I want to get back to Activity Menu and close the Guns activity. And I used your code, still got error: 01-02 13:02:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(8757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 13:02:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(8757): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {guns.com/guns.com.pushke} did not call through to super.onDestroy()

Comment: bit confusing from where you want to start mediaplayer and from where you are going to stop/release the mediaplayer

Comment: I am using in Guns activity Media Player, and I want it to stop/release when I go back to Menu

Comment: then try replacing the onDestroy() method with onPause() method and let me know.

Comment: Still getting error but this time in logcat:01-02 13:20:26.627: E/AndroidRuntime(10910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 13:20:26.627: E/AndroidRuntime(10910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {guns.com/guns.com.pushke}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I think your final mediaplayer was disturbing now try edited part by replacing your onCreate() method.

Comment: Damn how could I miss that final. It worked now problem was in that Final! Appreciate your help man! respect

Answer (score 0):

In On destroy before releasing media player please stop the media player

Comment: better you put mp.stop() and release in a try catch block, because media player has some error codec problems